# Singular or plural verb after a singular noun denoting a quantity?

Tags: множественное-число

Sometimes you use a word-combination of 2 nouns to denote a quantity of entities: «большинство людей». Should a singular or plural form be used for a verb after that? I.e., «большинство людей не знает» or «большинство людей не знают»? Why?

Comment: See (http://gramota.ru/spravka/letters/?rub=bolshinstvo). To put long story short, both ways are possible.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Both are used, i.e. in modern Russian these two forms are interchangeable in many context. Though, not always.

1. If it **isn't** a two-word combination, but a single word denoting some concept which is formally a word in singular — then only formal grammatical agreement is correct, i.e. singular: *Большинство не знает*.
2. Plural agreement is recommended in the following cases:

   - if you need to stress that the actions were performed independently and/or that the agents were active rather than passive: Большинство студентов хорошо написали дипломы.
   - if you have a long sentence and there are many words between the subject and the object: formal agreement will sound less clear in this case (you'll have to re-read the sentence to realise that the subject is formally a singular construction)
   - when you have several predicates: Большинство родителей любят своих детей, но не всегда знают их друзей.
   - if you have an adjectival phrase in plural that describes the subject. if the predicate contains adjective in plural: Большинство кошек в питомнике *были полосатыми*.

from http://www.gramota.ru/spravka/letters/?rub=bolshinstvo

Answer (score 4):

Actually, both are possible and interchangeable, according to the Russian grammar rules.

For example,

> Большинство граждан проголосовал**о** за нового президента
>   Большинство граждан проголосовал**и** за нового президента

The second option is preferable:

1. When the subject is separated from the predicate with another parts of the sentence:

   - Множество замечаний по содержанию диссертации и оформлению библиографии **были высказаны** молодому аспиранту.
2. When the subject is separated from the predicate by an attributive construction:

   - Часть средств, вырученных от продажи книги, **пойдут** на содержание больниц.
3. If the action of every participant is important:

   - Ряд сотрудников нашей организации **выступили** с этой инициативой.
4. If there are two predicates:

   - Ряд учеников не считают выполнение домашних заданий необходимым и **приходят** на урок неподготовленными.
5. If the predicate is formed by a noun or an adjective in plural:

   - Большинство домов в этой деревне **были** деревянными.

Answer (score 1):

- Большинство проголосовало
- Люди, составляющие большинство, проголосовали

In the first case, you are talking about a single entity - Большинство.

In the second, many entities, Люди.

Большинство людей is still a single entity. Людей is just a qualifier.