# Много людей (знает/знают)

Tags: грамматика, глаголы

I encountered this phrase: "Много людей в Европе и Америке знает о Петербурге."

The subject is intuitively plural, so I expected "знают" - "Много людей знают...".

When are singular verbs used in Russian for a plural subject?

Comment: Related: [Singular or plural verb after a singular noun denoting a quantity?](http://russian.stackexchange.com/q/5663/2060)

Comment: Is "Много людей в Европе и Америке" considered "formally a word in singular"?

Comment: @RudyReeves Speaker decides. Roughly saying, "Много людей знает" = "Many people know", and "Много людей знает" =  "A large group of people knows". Unlike in English, Russian speakers are OK with the latter.

Comment: in my personal view, you are right. It should be `знают`. But also you should get used to the fact that not always colloquial Russian is "correct" from a purist's point of view. A verb in the singular form with a plural noun is not rare, like in the example you provided.

Comment: I have another explanation for this. If some plural noun is considered as a whole than we use a plural form of a verb. But in this situation it is like the object in question is a single item, and the fact, that there are a lot of such items. It sounds like a short form of `[Есть] Много людей в Европе и Америке [, каждый из которых ] знает о Петербурге`. It is actually pretty common

Answer (score 5):

Sorry for a long quote in Russian.

Rosenthal, 184:

> В рассматриваемой конструкции (*Q: сказуемое при счётном обороте*) сказуемое может иметь как форму единственного, так и форму множественного числа. Ср.: *Вошло семь человек погони... (Лесков). – Наутро пятьдесят семь выходцев подали заявления с просьбой принять в колхоз (Шолохов).*
>
> На выбор формы числа, помимо указанных выше условий согласования сказуемого с подлежащим – собирательным существительным, влияет также ряд других условий.
>
> 1. Форма единственного числа сказуемого указывает на совместное действие, форма множественного числа – на раздельное совершение действия. Ср.: *Пять солдат отправилось в разведку (группой). – Пять солдат отправились в разведку (каждый с самостоятельным заданием); К началу экзамена явилось десять студентов. – Десять студентов окончили институт с отличием.* Ср. также различное согласование однородных сказуемых в одном и том же предложении: *Человек полтораста солдат высыпало из лесу и с криком устремились на вал (Пушкин)* (в первом случае характеризуется совместность действия, во втором – раздельность).
> 2. Форма единственного числа сказуемого указывает на совокупность предметов, форма множественного числа – на отдельные предметы. Ср.: *В городе строится пять объектов соцкультбыта (единое нерасчлененное представление о действии). – В крупнейших городах страны строятся еще пять объектов соцкультбыта (расчлененное представление о действии).* Ср. также: *В крендельной работало двадцать шесть человек... (Горький). – Восемь самолетов полка взлетали попарно, соблюдая очередь (Н. Чуковский).* Поэтому при подлежащем, обозначающем большое число предметов и воспринимаемом как одно целое, сказуемое обычно ставится в единственном числе, например: *В столовой в одну смену сидело сто человек (Макаренко); Прибыло шестьсот студентов-путейцев (Н. Островский).*
> 3. Форма единственного числа сказуемого употребляется при обозначении меры веса, пространства, времени и т.д., так как в этом случае имеется в виду единое целое, например: *На покраску крыши ушло двадцать килограммов олифы; До конца пути оставалось пятнадцать километров; На выполнение всей работы понадобится шесть месяцев.*
> 4. Сказуемые-глаголы (обычно со значением протекания времени) ставятся в единственном числе, если в составе количественно-именного сочетания (обычно оборота) имеются слова *лет, месяцев, дней, часов* и т.д., например: *Прошло сто лет (Пушкин); Однако уже, кажется, одиннадцать часов пробило (Тургенев); Вот два года моей жизни вычеркнуто (Горький).* Но при другом лексическом значении глагола возможна форма множественного числа сказуемого, например: *Десять секунд показались мне за целый час (Л. Толстой).*

In a nutshell: plural and singular can both be used, unless it's a special case (measures of length, weight, intervals of time etc. govern singural) or a nuance in meaning you want to stress (whether the subject is perceived as a group as a whole or many separate entities).

This discrepancy is a remnant of Old Russian, which used an adjective in neuter plural instead of an adverb in constructs like that (compare *многая лета; святая святых; вся суть; прочая, прочая, прочая* etc), and this adjective used to be the subject in the sentence.

This form coinsides with the feminine singular, and, since the gender and the number of the subject governs the verb, both plural and singular forms of the verb were perceived as acceptable.

Comment: If you quote Rosenthal, you need to refer to par. 12: `При наличии в составе подлежащего слов много, мало, немного, немало, сколько, столько преобладает форма единственного числа сказуемого, однако в последнее время, в связи с общей тенденцией к согласованию по смыслу, форма множественного числа находит все более широкое распространение.`

Answer (score 4):

The subject here is *много* and it is singular.

Comment: So how will you explain that "Много людей знают..." is valid too?

Comment: For the sake of fairness it must be said: Много людей знают - does not sound very nice. Многие люди знают sounds better, if somebody really wants to use plural form of the verb.

Answer (score 2):

The choice between these two verb forms depends on the topic parsing. Notice that in Russian syntax the first word/phrase is [usually] a topic with the subsequent words being hierachially structured commentaries. This means *людей* is a genitive attribute to *много* (cf. with phrases like *много людей - это хорошо*).

Sometimes the topic can be positioned at the end of a phrase (not being a grammatical subject, as in the examples below).

E.g. to my Russian ear the most natural parcing here wourd be [*много]людей*], not [*много людей*], hence, the subject is ***много*** and it takes a singular verb form, just like in any impersonal phrase, cf.

*Было мало/много времени* (the topic is *время* and the subject is 'zero', or impersonal)

*Было* (not *были) много/мало дел.* (the topic is *дела* and the subject is 'zero', or impersonal)

*Ожидается* (not *ожидаются) много осадков.*